# How to update certain element of array in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array looking like this

```
[0...99]

0: {field1: 'test1', field2: test2}
1: {field1: 'test3', field2: test4}
...
```

I created the array like this
 `array:any = [];`
And I added data using `push()` how can i update the data of element `n` later?

Initialisation part

```
for(this.j = 0; this.j< this.accNum; this.j++) {
  this.array.push({ field1:'test1', field2:'' });
  
  this.http1
    .get(this.url.concat(this.array[this.j]?.field1))
    .subscribe((response1: any) => {
      this.array[this.j].field2 = 'test2';
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, could you add a sample of how you add the data to the array? Judging from your reply to @Eino Gourdin's answer, the problem might actually be on the initialisation part.

Comment: Is there any chance is because of the API?
```

Comment: ```
for(this.j = 0; this.j< this.accNum; this.j++)
          {
            this.array.push({ 
              field1:'test1',
       field2:''
              
            })
            this.http1.get(this.url.concat(this.array[this.j]?.field1)).subscribe(
            (response1: any) => {
             this.array[this.j].field2 = 'test2';})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seeing your code in the comment, I think I now know what it's happening.

The problem is that you are using a variable whose value has long been updated. Take a look at the following code:

```js
let i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Notice the following:

- The `i` variable is declared outside of the loop (this mimics your `this.j` behaviour).
- The loop finishes completely before the first `console.log` has a chance to run (basically, the `setTimeout` make the code to run asynchronously). In this case, the `setTimeout` mimics your API call.

By the time the `setTimeout` runs, the loop has completely run leaving the `i` variable with the value of 5. So, sure enough, [if you run this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlg3AUAMwPYCcIAooQLwQAwzQQA8EArIVANRUCUEA3nBBAM7gAqUAtiEgK5h06etgB8jZiwgBjJADtWSUADpgSAOaZa8FgF8ANBACMeMzrh6gA) you will see that you get `5` printed 5 times instead of the expected `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

Also notice that the printed value is `5` instead of the last "correct" value for this loop which would be `4`. If you translate this to arrays, the result is that you are always accessing the element `length + 1` which, obviously it does not exist.

What you need to do to fix your problem is to scope the the value of `this.j` inside the loop. For example:

```js
let i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ((k) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(k);
    }, 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

With this code, what I'm doing it to create an anonymous function inside the loop and passing `i` to it (which gets it's value as `k`). By doing this, I'm setting `k` in the scope with the right value for the `setTimeout` and `console.log` to run.

Now, [if you run this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlg3AUAMwPYCcIAooQLwQAwzQQA8EArIVANRUCUEA3nBBugNb3YB8jzLEAZ3AAVKAFsQSAK5h06Tjyb9+AYyQA7AUlAA6YEgDm7WvGUBfADQQAjHjsm+Z2pgdmgA), you will see that the result is, indeed, the expected one.

A more elegant way of doing this is by calling an external function instead:

```js
function requestAPI(i) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000);
}


let i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  requestAPI(i);
}
```

Here it is a more suitable example for your case:

```js
const values = [];
function requestAPI(i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    values[i].field2 = 'test2';
  }, 1000);
}


let i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  values.push({ field1: 'test1', field2:'' });
  requestAPI(i);
}

setTimeout(() => console.log(values), 2000);
```

[You can run it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYFcCmEYF4YG0C6A3AFABmKYwUAluDAE5oCO60AggAoCSAFNQJQwA3sRgwIaKABVqAWzQgUUHj0FYAfMNFj4yVrmr4AdKWpokAEwBM2GAHIoGKFbskxAXwA0MAIwAGAP4Sd2JQpEkYahJSEHoYPls-QkiYAB4YAFZk6gBqHMERMURUDCMABxQIAAseIRhTcwsfAC57R2gfO28GyytmuzsYdyDtRhYnTl4BYNCJaTkFJRU1TVBIEHCjJBAAcx5i1n5vKwC-IKA).

I suggest you search for the topic of `variable scope` in Javascript.

Comment: thanks man it worked but using your less elegant way, thanks!!